# How to avoid running code on head node of the cluster

Tags: matlab, slurm, sbatch

I am using a cluster to run my code. I use a runm file to run my code on the cluster. runm script is as below:

```
#!/bin/sh 
#SBATCH --job-name="....."
#SBATCH -n 4
#SBATCH --output=bachoutput
#SBATCH --nodes=1-1
#SBATCH -p all
#SBATCH --time=1-01:00:00
matlab <znoDisplay.m>o1
```

today, when my code was running I received an email from cluster boss which says please don't run your code on the head node and use other nodes. I did a lot of searches but I couldn't find that how can I have changed the node from the main node to other nodes. Could anyone help me? Is there any script which could be used in runm to change it?

Could anyone help me to avoid running my code on head node?

Comment: How come you're using just the script and not `matlab -nodisplay -nosplash <your_script.m>`? `-nosdisplay` prevents GUI and `-nosplash` prevents MATLABs logo from popping up.

Comment: Yes, definitely try it. Also @damienfrancois solution is likely the right thing to do combined with these options.

Comment: One more question: why shouldn't one run a code on the head node of a cluster? Is it slower to run a code on head node? @atru

Comment: The head node is meant for mundane tasks; compiling, file management, job submission, there is often only a couple of them. Compute nodes are for computations, there are plenty of them.

Comment: Basically running jobs on the head node is like deciding to hop in the locomotive rather than getting properly seated in one of the cars when travelling with the train.

Comment: @atru Could you please if you can help me here?  Could you please help me? Answer and comments doesn't help me to run the code. I asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953452/matlab-code-doesnt-run-in-cluster-properly

Comment: @atru Should I use  matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash < yourScript.m instead of what I used before?

Comment: please see above comment. @damienfrancois

Comment: Yes, you should definitely -nodisplay and -nosplash - you don't need -nojvm though. @damienfrancois - nice explanation :) I think I'll borrow it in the future..

Answer (score 4):

If the Matlab process was running on the head node, it means you did not submit your script but you most probably simply ran it.

Make sure to submit it with

```
sbatch runm
```

Then you can see it waiting in the queue (or running) with

```
squeue -u $USER
```

and check that it is not running on the frontend with

```
top
```

Also note @atru's comment about the Matlab options `-nodisplay` and `-nosplash` for Matlab to work properly in batch mode.

Comment: Could you please help me? Answer and comments doesn't help me to run the code. I asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953452/matlab-code-doesnt-run-in-cluster-properly